# Package "main" and func "main"

Tags: go

The intro/sample go progs I've seen and experimented with start with

```
package main
```

and have

```
func main()
```

Is there any relationship between the "main" in the package line and the "main" in the func line?  I'm guessing not. C/C++ uses the same "main" entry point.  Just want to make sure though.  I haven't seen any docs that say the use of "main" is just a coincidence.

Comment: Of course it's not a *coincidence*, they are both named that for a good reason.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The entry point for the application is the `main` function in the `main` package   [as described in the specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution):

> A complete program is created by linking a single, unimported package called the *main package* with all the packages it imports, transitively. The main package must have package name `main` and declare a function `main` that takes no arguments and returns no value.
>
> ```
> func main() { … }
> ```
>
> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then invoking the function `main`. When that function invocation returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete.

The language specification does not give special meaning to the name `main` outside of this context. The name `main` is not a reserved name.

It's OK to declare a `main` function in non-main packages. In such cases, it's just a function named `main`.

Comment: But what of func main() in files which are in some package other than main?

Comment: @Jeff If the package is not `main`, then the function is not the application entry point.  It's just a function named `main`.

Comment: Okay, is naming a function main() outside of the main package unusual practice or does it signify intent? Afaict, in the case I am seeing, the code somehow gets built into something that can be invoked from the command line.

Comment: It seems this was asked separately (https://stackoverflow.com/q/50706238/5419599) but still isn't clear as to whether it's a bad idea, an antipattern, or something that no one cares about.