# Golang func main() in packages other than main?

Tags: go

In the case, for example, of `helloworld`, the name of the package is main and there is also a `func main()` statement. But I have also seen code which `func main()` which is in some other package. The code, however, seems like it might be used as a standalone program. So what does it mean to have a `func main()` with a package statement other than `package main`?

Comment: It means nothing. If the author ascribed some other meaning to the function, you would have to ask the author.

Comment: When you say it means nothing, would the code not work?

Comment: It works just fine, you can test it out yourself. It's just a function called `main`, and nothing else. Without the actual code, we have no idea what the intent was, but you can't compile a non main package as a main package.

Comment: The entry point to a Go program is the function `main()` in the package `main`. A function `main` in any other package is just a function called `main`. It's not a reserved keyword.

Comment: Good question Jeff, I advise you to be careful with trusting confusing code. Code should always be as simple and unambiguous as possible

Answer (score 9):

The Go programming language is defined by its specification.

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Program execution](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution)
>
> A complete program is created by linking a single, unimported package
>   called the *main* package with all the packages it imports,
>   transitively. The *main* package must have package name `main` and declare
>   a function `main` that takes no arguments and returns no value.
>
> ```
> func main() { … }
> ```
>
> Program execution begins by initializing the *main* package and then
>   invoking the function `main`. When that function invocation returns, the
>   program exits. It does not wait for other (*non-main*) goroutines to
>   complete.

---

The function name `main` has no special significance outside `package main`.

Comment: I would guess this is overall a bad practice, then?  Or is it?